# Change pivot source through VBA

Tags: vba, excel-2007

I get "Invalid procedure or call" when I use the code below in order to change the pivot source range in VBA. What is the right syntax for doing this? Thanks in advance.

```
Dim DataArea As Variant
'...    
DataArea = "Raw_Data!R1C1:R" & Selection.Rows.Count & "C" & Selection.Columns.Count
Sheets("Pivot-view").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
   PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=DataArea, _
   Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `DataArea` is a *valid, named range* in your workbook, then the reference to it in your macro needs to be in quotes; therefore, update

`SourceData:=DataArea,`

to become

`SourceData:="DataArea",`